# How to apply a postprocess effect to a UI element

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, hlsl, cg, unity3d-gui

I have a post-process effect that uses Unity's `Graphics.Blit` to pixelate or apply a `crt-screen` effect to a scene. There are some UI elements that display after the fact (basically making it not a true post process, but let's put that aside for a moment).

Now, I want to apply a second process that performs a screen wipe and transitions out one scene for another. This time I want to include the UI buttons in the effect.

I've looked into using a render texture and then rendering to a second camera, but I feel like there is a smarter/more accurate way to handle this.

**1st version of this question:**

Can I selectively include the `screenspace-overlay` UI in the script that applies the post process?

**or, 2nd version of this question**

Is there a trick to getting the render texture to preserve resolution and display accurately (i.e.: without lost quality) when re rendering to a second camera?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?